# UML - interfaces, abstract classes or...?

Tags: interface, uml, virtual, abstract, class-diagram

I have some abstract "module" for my program.
Let's say it's a GUI module.
It contains only the interface for the module and its types - for compatibility with other modules (in the other module I can use GUI module and its types, not bothering about it's implementation).

So I have sth like that:

```
GUI::Component //represent the abstract component (button, label etc.)
//so it's only the base class for components

GUI::Clickable //if any component is clickable, it must inherit from it

GUI::Button : public Component, public Clickable
GUI::Label : public Component
```

But even a `Label` or `Button` have only virtual methods (I guess they are interfaces of the module). The GUI module impementation's e.g. `SomeGUIImp` has to declare `SomeButton : public GUI::Button` and `SomeLabel : public GUI::Label` (and they will be transparent for user, because of the object factory).

**I don't want to change anything in the code**, I just want to **make a proper UML diagram for it**.

Are all that elements (`Component, Clickable, Button`) interfaces? Or abstract classes?

I would like to show somehow , that the `Label` and `Button` are "less abstract" (can be used by user more directly, are more specified) than `Component`.

Also, it would be nice to show the difference between `Clickable` (it's functionality) and `Component` (it's an abstract base for all components).

### Current solution (not sure of it)

I can't say 100% why, but in my opinion, maybe the `Clickable` is an interface, `Component` is an abstract class and `Button` is just the regular class.

But that shows the relations inside the module, ignoring that `Button` (which have only pure virtual methods) also is just the declaration for some module's implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C++ doesn't have the notion of an interface, when a class is 100% abstract (virtual) you can model it both as an interface or as an abstract class. In your description these classes are closer semantically to interfaces, so modeling them that way would be good. The direction you are taking seems very good IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is very simple - classes with only pure virtual methods are interfaces, classes with part of the methods pure virtual are abstract classes, class with no virtual methods are implementation classes. If that doesn't fit into your design, you probably should rethink some things. For example, if you think of `Button` both as interface and as regular class, you should probably split it into 2 distinct classes - one for interface and one for implementation.