# What are pure virtual methods in UML?

Tags: uml

I am attempting to understand how I should use the realization of interfaces and the implementation of abstract classes in UML. I came across the post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438187/700543 whereby the poster states that pure virtual methods are interfaces whilst those that are part pure virtual methods are abstract classes. Is anyone able to give me a real world scenario and not one based on code?

Comment: Code is real-world; any attempt to create a UML diagram almost certainly results in code, unless the UML diagram is just an exploratory exercise.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - It is mostly exploratory in my world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Interface is only a "class skeleton" for library users to extend, and as you said, methods cannot be implemented. An Abstract class can have implemented methods. I will give you a real life example:

Imagine I provide an Interface for people to implement sorting functions and I also provide a Class for bench marking sorting functions. My bench marking class only needs to know what methods of the Interface it needs to call in order to perform the bench marking, it does not know how they are implemented. Therefore, inside the bench marking class you might only see something like `sortInterfaceInstace.getNumberOfSwap()`, whereas `sortInterfaceInstance` is only known to be of `sortInterface` type at compile time, and not of any specific user sort implementation.

If you need implemented methods, use abstract instead of interfaces.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't follow your example. Would appreciate some basic examples e.g. car and its driver.

Comment: An Interface is the blue print of a car. An Abstract class is a car with no motor and no driver. If you follow The Interface(blue print) you can construct your own car. If you put a motor in the car (extend the abstract class with some child class) , and if you place a driver there (instantiate the said child class), then you have a driver driving a car. You cannot drive a blue print nor can you drive an unfinished car. You can only drive finished cars (either by extending abstract classes or implementing interfaces).

Comment: After constructing a car with with the blue print (Implementing the interface), you can also drive that car if it is a finished one (non-abstract implementation of the interface).

Answer (score 0):

An interface only describes how something can be used, it provides none of the underlying implementation of how it gets done, i.e. a class with only pure virtual functions. An English analogy for an interface may be an adjective.

One example of an interface is a Movable interface. This interface may provide one pure virtual function move which tells the object to move to a given location. However, how it moves there is not implemented.

An abstract class on the other hand differs from an interface in that it provides some of the implementation details, but not all of them. These are conceptually high-level items that can be manipulated in certain ways, but when you get down to it the high-level item doesn't really exists or make sense by itself.

For example, say we have an abstract Shape class. The shape can have a certain origin which can be tracked independent of what Shape it is. The functions to transform the shape can be declared and implemented in the Shape class, saving the hassle of having to provide the same implementation in each sub-class. However, when you try to get the area or perimeter of the shape it's difficult to answer this without knowing more about the shape.

Comment: Thanks but that just went past my head. Are you able to give me a simpler example e.g. car and its driver or language and how it is spoken e.g. English, French, etc?